# How to get rid of extra bullets in my unordered list?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list, unordered

Hi I am printing an array to my DOM using an input method. I can get the user input to print out the list, but there are too many bullets. Here is my code below:

```
function addPokemon() {
    var pokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemon-name-container");
    pokemonName.innerHTML = document.getElementById("pokemon-names").value;

    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        if (typeof element[i].value !== "undefined") {
            pokemonArray.push(element[i].value);
        }
    }
    console.log(pokemonArray);
    for (var i = 0; i < pokemonArray.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("pokemon-container").innerHTML += "<li>" + pokemonArray[i] + "<li>";
    }
}

var pokemonArray = [];
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("move-container");
```

How can this be fixed?
[image]

Added what element was for those asking

[image]

Comment: What is `element` ?

Comment: There's a lot missing here: what is `element`? Where/how is `pokemonArray` declared? What does the HTML look like for the `pokemon-names` element? etc\

Comment: Just added a new pic of my HTML and explained where element and pokemonArray is coming from

Answer (score 3):

To close `<li>`, you need a `/`,

```
document.getElementById("pokemon-container").innerHTML += "<li>" + pokemonArray[i] + "</li>";
```

What's happening is that the browser autocloses your first `<li>` as soon as it sees the other `<li>`. Then it treats that other `<li>` as another item, auto-closing that as well.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't see that other empty `<li>` in the OP

Comment: Thanks this fixed it right up. One more thing I might ask, How do I get the name "Charmander" to be on the top instead of the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you did not close your list item element before you started to append another one.

> ```js
> .innerHTML += "<li>" + pokemonArray[i] + "<li>"; // The 2nd one not closing...
> ```

It is implicitly creating an empty list item after each of the ones you want.

---

### Example

I made up the DOM, because you did not provide it.

```js
const pokemonArray = [];
const element = document.querySelectorAll('.pokemon');

addPokemon();

function addPokemon() {
  var pokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemon-name-container");
  pokemonName.innerHTML = document.getElementById("pokemon-names").value;

  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    if (typeof element[i].value !== "undefined") {
      pokemonArray.push(element[i].value);
    }
  }
  console.log(pokemonArray);
  for (var i = 0; i < pokemonArray.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("pokemon-container").innerHTML += "<li>" + pokemonArray[i] + "</li>";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="input" id="pokemon-names" />

<input type="text" class="pokemon" value="Bulbasaur" />
<input type="text" class="pokemon" value="Charmander" />
<input type="text" class="pokemon" value="Squirtle" />

<ul id="pokemon-name-container"></ul>

<ul id="pokemon-container"></ul>
```

---

### Using JavaScript to manipulate the DOM

A better way to do this would be to to create the DOM elements in JavaScript and append them to the container. You could also store a state and re-render the list every time you add a new Pokémon.

```js
const POKEMON_NAMES = [ 'Bulbasaur', 'Charmander', 'Squirtle' ];

const state = {
  pokemon: []
};

let sel = document.querySelector('.available-pokemon');
sel.appendChild(new Option('', ''));
POKEMON_NAMES.forEach(name => sel.appendChild(new Option(name, name)));

sel.addEventListener('change', addPokemon);

function addPokemon(e) {
  let selectedPokemon = e.currentTarget.value;
  if (selectedPokemon.length > 0 && !state.pokemon.includes(selectedPokemon)) {
    state.pokemon.push(selectedPokemon);
    renderPokemonList();
  }
}

function renderPokemonList() {
  let container = document.querySelector('.pokemon-container');
  emptyElement(container);
  state.pokemon.sort().forEach(pokemon => {
    let listItem = document.createElement('LI');
    listItem.textContent = pokemon;
    container.appendChild(listItem);
  });
}

function emptyElement(element) {
  while (element.firstChild) {
    element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
  }
}
```

```css
.pokemon-container {
  border: thin solid grey;
  min-height: 1em;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
}
```

```html
<select class="available-pokemon"></select>
<ul class="pokemon-container"></ul>
```